# magento 2 change store id

Tags: multistore, query, store-id

I have a multi store Magento 2 site and I need to change the ID of one of the stores.  Is there any easy way to do this?  I tried to run an update query on the store table but I get and error because of foreign key constraints.  It seems like there is about 150 references to the store table.  Any easy way to update the store id in the store table?

Comment: Changing a store id in Magento is almost impossible. Pretty much every logic depends on the store id to work. You are better of creating a new store and migrating any data to it.

Comment: I never thought about creating a new store and migrating the data over to it, that just might work.

Comment: @TrevorOrr please share further information about why you want to change it. I bet you can fix your problem from other side :)